# which select operator is fastest in jquery

Tags: jquery

Which is the fastest selection operator in jquery? I don't have any options to check the time taken by the selection process in jquery.

1. `$('#mydiv')` or;
2. `$('.mydiv')` or;
3. multi select or any other selection process

Could not judge whether `id selector` or `class selector` is faster

Comment: see http://jsperf.com/id-vs-class-vs-tag-selectors/2

Comment: Read this: [**`Optimize Selectors`**](http://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/)

Comment: `$(id)` > `$(class)` > `.find()` > `.filter()` -- Use `.find()`/`.filter()` instead of the jQuery selectors such as `:even` and `:not` as they're faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id Selector is faster than class Selector

used this link to show the difference between id and class and which one is fastest.

http://www.sitepoint.com/efficient-jquery-selectors/

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/forms/article.php/3895776